# Визуализация звука с помощью библиотеки BASS на C#

Tags: c#, аудио, bass.dll

Здравствуйте. Недавно занялся написанием плеера на C#. Хотелось бы сделать визуализацию звука, вроде графических образов WMP. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?[image: Как пример]

Comment: что именно реализовать? Алгоритм генерации образов? Просто рендер чего то?

Comment: Не ту библиотеку выбрали. Надо было [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @tym32167 Сам алгоритм генерации образов

Comment: @Bulson Хорошо, попробую, спасибо

Comment: И можно ли вообще это сделать в WinForms, или нужно переходить на WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Для получения графического представления звука нужно использовать метод [BASS_ChannelGetData](http://bass.radio42.com/help/html/a13cfef0-1056-bb94-81c4-a4fdf21bd463.htm) с флагом `BASS_DATA_FFT...` Метод возвращает массив амплитуд для набора диапазонов частот. Из него нужно отбросить первый элемент (0 Гц - это постоянная составляющая), и построить график по относительным значениям амплитуды и частоты.

Пример кода для вывода графика в Windows Forms (на форме нужно поместить элементы Button, Panel и Timer):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Un4seen.Bass;

namespace BassTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int chan = 0;//номер потока
        Single[] fft=null;//массив данных спектра

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n=Bass.BASS_GetDevice();//получаем устройство по умолчанию
            if (Bass.BASS_Init(n, 44100, 0, IntPtr.Zero) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("BASS_Init failed");
                return;
            }

            chan = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(@"C:\MP3\file.mp3",
                0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);//создаем поток в режиме FLOAT

            if (chan == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("BASS_StreamCreateFile failed");
                return;
            }

            bool f;
            f = Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(chan, false);//воспроизводим поток
            if (f == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("BASS_ChannelPlay failed");
                return;
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)//запускаем каждые 500 мс
        {
            if (chan == 0) return;
            if (Bass.BASS_ChannelIsActive(chan) != BASSActive.BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING) return;

            fft = new Single[2048];//выделяем массив для данных            
            Bass.BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, fft, (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FFT4096);//получаем спектр потока
            fft[0] = 0.0f;//избавляемся от постоянной составляющей            

            panel1.Refresh();//перерисовка графика
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)//построение графика
        {
            if (fft == null) return;            

            PointF p1,p2;            
            float max_y = 0;//максимальное значение амплитуды
            float min_y=Single.MaxValue;//минимальное значение амплитуды
            float max_x = fft.Length - 1;//максимальная частота, для которой амплитуда ненулевая

            int i = 0;
            max_x = 0;
            foreach(float f in fft)//находим максимальные и минимальные значения
            {
                if (f > max_y) max_y = f;
                if (f < min_y) min_y = f;

                if (f > 0.001f) max_x = (float)i;
                i++;
            }             

            /*меняем направление оси Y, чтобы она смотрела вверх*/
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0f,-1.0f);
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.0f, -1.0f * panel1.Height);

            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

            float y;
            p1 = new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f);//начальная точка

            for (float x = 1; x <= max_x; x++)
            {                
                y = fft[(int)x];

                /*вычисляем координату следующей точки по относительной амплитуде*/
                p2 = new PointF((x / max_x) * panel1.Width, panel1.Height * (y - min_y) / (max_y - min_y));

                path.AddLine(p1, p2);//добавляем линию в график
                p1 = p2;
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);

        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит так (не настолько красиво, как в WMP, но уже что-то):

[image: BASS FFT]