# Как вытащить массив частот из системы для отображения в виде графика в консоли?

Tags: c++, c, аудио, графика

Как вытащить массив частот из системы? Моя задача - нарисовать синусоидную живую гистограмму звука на С++ в консоли(может и не в консоли). Теоретически надо перетащить вот эту штукенцию из настроек(вложена картинка).[image: Картинка]

Звук вашей системе(например, при прослушивании музыки) взаимодействует и хранится в числовой последовательности. Эти числа и есть те частоты, с помощью который выводится звук. Как их получить=)?

Comment: Что за система?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что изображено на картинке, вовсе не частота. Эта полоска из параметров звукового устройства в Windows 10 показывает среднюю или пиковую амплитуду звука за короткий период времени. Именно это значение характеризует ощущаемую громкость. Программно пиковую амплитуду в Windows можно получить с использованием так называемых [Peak meters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters) (интерфейс IAudioMeterInformation в WASAPI).

> Звук вашей системе(например, при прослушивании музыки) взаимодействует и хранится в числовой последовательности. Эти числа и есть те частоты, с помощью который выводится звук. Как их получить=)?

Это не совсем так. Последовательность чисел в PCM Audio - это не частоты, это мгновенные значения смещения колеблющейся частицы гипотетического тела, источника звука, от положения равновесия. Для получения данных воспроизводимого звука используется механизм [Loopback Recording](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording). Пример есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794133/240512

Частота же, в случае сложного звука, беспорядочно изменяется в каждый момент времени и массив частот как таковой не имеет смысла. Обычно говорят о спектре частот, то есть таблице, в которой показано, какая доля энергии звука приходится на определенную частоту. Диаграмма при этом выглядит не полоской, а [графиком кривой линии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746793/240512) с пиками на месте гармоник, вид которой меняется во времени. Для получения спектров на основе данных PCM Audio (это называется преобразованием Фурье) есть разные библиотеки, например [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/).

Comment: А возможно в таком случае нарисовать динамичную синусоиду к этому графику?

Comment: @ВладиславВ. Конечно можно. Но это будет очень сложный код. По сути, задача складывается из трех составляющих, получение звука через WASAPI Loopback (пример на С++ есть по ссылке), получение спектра и рисование графика. А вот график средней/пиковой интенсивности построить проще, есть готовый пример на С++: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879984/240512